# How to display json in emberJS?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ember.js

Im very new to the "JS Framework topic" and now I try to

1. Get data from a json-file
2. Display it in a table

Later I want to filter/sort the data, but I want to do it step by step.

What I came up with so far:

## app.js

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({
            async: false
        });
        $.getJSON("json/json_10k.json", function(json) {
            return json;
        });
    }
});
```

## index.html (part of it):

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
  <ul>
  {{#each item in model}}
    <li>:{{item.Id}}</li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

Now, I dont see any data/errors. Maybe somebody have an idea, what could be wrong here.

Comment: You might want to try to echo the json in the "getJSON" function before returning it. Then you can localize the problem. If the data *loading* isn't the problem then you should try to make an JSFiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @FlorianW. T. The Loading is fine (I checked with Firebug). I guess the problem is, that the getJSON() is async and the data is not returned?

Comment: I think `model` written this way requires a promise as a return, since you technically can't return a value from a callback that way. My Ember is rusty, try `return $.getJSON(...`

Comment: You cannot return ajax data like that (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) so your model is most likely empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really want to use `async:false` you can try the other way around

```js
$.ajaxSetup({
  async: false
});

$.getJSON("json/json_10k.json", function(json) {
  App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: json
  });
});
```

Or return like this

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({
            async: false
        });
        return $.getJSON("json/json_10k.json").responseText; 
               // you maybe need to JSON.parse() here
        // return $.parseJSON($.getJSON("json/json_10k.json").responseText);
    }
});
```